# Openstack new instance - could not find capabilities for domaintype=kvm

Tags: openstack

my Lab:

```
1 IBM System x3650 M4 - U18.04 with MAAS
1 IBM System x3650 M4 - U18.04 with KVM (1Vm JUJU and 4Vm for OPENSTACK)
```

I've used Maas & Juju to deploy Openstack on 4 KVM node, all tasks are went well but if I try to launch a new instance receive this error

```
Error: Failed to perform requested operation on instance "u1804Ins", the instance has an error status: Please try again later [Error: Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exceeded max scheduling attempts 3 for instance cca778d5-a1e4-4f53-a31b-52797d97e9ce. Last exception: invalid argument: could not find capabilities for domaintype=kvm ].
```

As shown here

[image]

what does that mean?

```
could not find capabilities for domaintype=kvm
```

Someone can help me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved using the suggestion presents on this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607212/launch-instance-in-openstack-always-results-in-error-no-valid-host-was-found?rq=1) and this [one](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/devstack-with-nested-kvm.html)

As reports this post, I've edited the my KVM Nodes via virsh utility:

**`$: sudo virsh edit compute-node01-vm`**

Change the lines below from:

```
<cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='full'>
  <model fallback='allow'>.......</model>
  ......
  ......
</cpu>
```

To

```
<cpu mode='host-passthrough' match='exact' check='full'>
  <model fallback='allow'>.......</model>
  ......
  ......
</cpu>
```

Then I've restart all the nodes from MAAS for the changes to take effect. And now I can add a new instance on Openstack

[image]